# Can I play D&D 4e solo?

Tags: dnd-4e, solo

I have played Dungeons & Dragons 4th edition for a long time now, and I am sorry to see it go. I liked the complexity of it, where as 5e is really based on quickly getting through encounters.

**Is it possible to play a completely solo D&D 4e game, on a budget?** In the Red Box, in the player's book, there is a little bit of a solo game at the end, but I cannot find another solo adventure anywhere. I know there is [this online game](http://dnd.chromesphere.com), but I'd like to play it on the tabletop.

Comment: When I was learning 4e, I used to play on my own to understand how things work, so its definitely possible. But am I understanding correctly that your question is more about the existence of a published adventure for you to follow?

Comment: If your concern is you won't be able to find players for 4th edition, I am sure that there will be people who don't transition to 5th edition. There are people still playing every edition of D&D, and there will be others who feel as you do.